# Ordenar lista en base a un orden predeterminado

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios, ordenamiento

Deseo ordenar cualquier lista de integers como

```
a = [1,20,300,346,343,9,0]
```

en base al orden de esta lista

```
b = [5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 2,0]
```

Lo realicé convirtiendo en diccionario la lista `b`, siendo la clave el numero y el valor una lista con los números ordenados:

```
d = {5: [], 4: [], 8: [], 9: [9], 1: [1], 7: [], 6: [], 3: [300, 346, 343], 2: [20], 0: [0]}
```

Ahora, también se tendrían que ordenar las listas del diccionario, teniendo en cuenta las decenas y unidades en el mismo orden de b.

Ejemplo: `[300, 346, 343]` tendría que ordenarse a `[346, 343, 300]`.

Por tanto, me gustaría que mi función fuese recurrente. y es ahí donde me lío con el diccionario, y sospecho que me estoy complicando. ¿iterar y ordenar? ¿usar list.index() y ordenar?

¿Alguna idea elegante para ordenar todos los números y devolver una única lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave es usar el argumento `key` de `sorted()` (perdón por el juego de palabras).

`sorted()` es una función de ordenación muy flexible. Para ordenar tiene que comparar los elementos, y cada tipo de datos puede tener su propio criterio sobre cómo debe ser ordenado en relación a otros. En tu caso los datos son enteros, y los enteros tienen predefinido un orden que no es el que te interesa.

Usando el parámetro `key` de `sorted()` le puedes pasar una función que recibirá un dato y retornará otro. Entonces `sorted()` llamará a esa función para cada uno de los datos a ordenar, y usará el resultado devuelto por ella como "clave" para comparar unos con otros. Así, por ejemplo, si al llamar a la función `clave(5)` te retorna `"hola"` y al llamar a `clave(3)` te retorna `"nunca"`, en lugar de comparar `5`  con `3` comparará `"hola"` con `"nunca"`. Al ser `"hola"` menor que `"nunca"` (pues las cadenas se comparan alfabéticamente), esto significará para `sorted()` que el `5` debe ir antes que el `3`.

Hay que pensar pues cómo implementar una función `clave()` que reciba un número de tu lista y retorne algo que sirva a `sorted()` para ordenarlo correctamente. Te dejo que lo pienses un poco... luego sigue.

> Spoiler. Tras esto viene la solución

Quieres ordenar los números en base al primer dígito, y si el primer dígito es igual, en base al siguiente, etc. En el fondo es una ordenación *lexicográfica* en vez de númerica, por lo que el primer paso será convertir cada número a cadena, pues las cadenas se ordenan lexicográficamente.

Una vez lo tenemos en cadena, podemos transformar cada cifra de esa cadena en otra, según la ordenación que tú buscas. En tu orden las cifras irían ordenadas así: 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 2,0. Es decir, la cifra `"5"` deberíamos transformarla en un `"0"`, pues queremos que sea la primera en la ordenación final, la cifra `"4"` se transformaría en `"1"`, etc.

Una vez transformadas todas las cifras, retornamos la cadena resultante.

Esta función hace lo descrito:

```
def clave(n):
  orden = "5489176320"
  v = []
  for cifra in str(n):
    indice = orden.index(cifra)
    v.append(str(indice))
  return "".join(v)
```

Probemos por ejempo con dos de los datos de tu lista, el 300 y el 346:

```
>>> clave(300)
'799'
>>> clave(346)
'716'
```

Usando esta función como `key` para `sorted`, cuando tenga que ordenar esos dos números, lo hará comparando las cadenas `"799"` y `"716"`. Ya que la segunda es lexicográficamente menor, determinará que el 346 debe ir antes del 300. Lo que es correcto.

Probemos entonces con tu serie de datos:

```
a = [1,20,300,346,343,9,0]
sorted(a, key=clave)
```

---

```
[9, 1, 346, 343, 300, 20, 0]
```

¡Ha funcionado! Parece magia :-)

Comment: Wow!! que elegante... que maravilla... como es Python... 
Y que gusto aprender de quienes saben. muchas gracias @abulafia.

Comment: solo una cosa.  la función clave necesita como argumento los elementos de la lista.  `TypeError: clave() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'`

Comment: Sí, la función debe admitir un parámetro, pero es `sorted()` quien la va llamando y se lo va pasando. Tú no la llamas, simplemente le das a `sorted` el nombre de la función a llamar. Fíjate en cómo he usado `sorted()` en el ejemplo: `key=clave`. Igual te equivocaste y pusiste `key=clave()`...

Comment: Cierto era eso. Mil gracias de nuevo..  
Pero no comprendo porque no se ha de poner los paréntesis en el nombre de la función a llamar. Es como si se asignara una variable, pero en realidad es una funcion... 
...este Python es una pasada!!  gracias por tu paciencia.

Comment: A ver, si pones los paréntesis estás llamando a la función, y asignarías entonces el resultado de llamarla. No quieres pasarle el resultado, sino la propia función para que sea él quien la llame. Una función es un "dato" más en python, se puede pasar como parámetro o se puede asignar a otra variable. Por ejemplo `f = clave`, y después puedes hacer `f(25)`, para llamar a `clave` pasandole 25.